# How to configure regex in XSLT so it doesn't match entity reference?

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am building an XSLT 2.0 stylsheet that accepts input similar to markdown and outputs XDP content (Adobe XML representation for PDF content).

To allow for special characters, such as * or [, they can be encoded in the input as \* or \[, respectively.

Before processing the markdown, I am converting such escape sequences to their entity references, e.g. \* to &#42; and \[ to &#91;, with the intention that they would not be matched for by regex expressions that need to match on the literal * or [ characters, for example.

**Edit**.  I thought problem was with [ and ], but as pointed out, encoding as entities doesn't work as I thought, they get matched the same way.

I am looking into possibly double encoding such values.  For example: Replace \* with &amp;#42;

In the XSLT output, is there a way to remove this double encoding, so that it is output as &#42;?

Comment: I would steer well clear of entities and anything involving ampersands. There are plenty of other choices that won't conflict with competing conventions, e.g. replace \* by §42§.

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking about it further, and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your non-match regex string contains an error:

```
regex="\*(.+?)\1"
```

That final `\1` should have been another `\*`. Correcting that shows the expected output

```
<match>[my text]</match>
<match>*my text*</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is working, as Michael Kay suggested, involves avoiding entities and anything involving ampersands.

In the input, match against an expression like `§(\d+)§`, and then for a match output the string corresponding to the codepoint:

```
<xsl:sequence select="codepoints-to-string(xs:integer(regex-group(1)))" />
```